# go to end of line of a textbox in appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

In appium(IOS), how to go to the end of a line. For selenium,

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.END).build().perform();
```

but this does not work for appium.
I have google a lot but not found any good reference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to achieve by "go to the end of line"?

Comment: In my test cases, first i want to click on text box which contains some text, than i want to go to the end of that text and than enter some text at the end.

Answer (score -2):

Just call `element.sendKeys("foo bar")`, the text will be append to the end.

Comment: In my IOS application, if you use sendkeys() using appium driver, it actually clear the previous data and and than insert the new data. But i don't want this. i want to keep my previous data, thats why i want to go to the last of the existing text first. Sorry your answer is not correct.